# HTTP Fileserver Response Intercept with URL rewrite

Tags: http, go

I am trying to write a middleware that will intercept all the files served by a `http.Fileserver` and re-write the URLs in the HTML files.  It is working okay to intercept the Write function but when I try to write the modified HTML back into the http.ResponseWriter it isn't working correctly.

The complete sample code can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/bradstimpson/c2b955122866d68e585c21cb1078aded

Copying here the response interceptor which works correctly:

```golang
type ResponseInterceptor interface {
    Write([]byte) (int, error)
}

type interceptor struct {
    w http.ResponseWriter
    o url.URL
    t url.URL
}

func NewResponseInterceptor(wri http.ResponseWriter, orig url.URL, targ url.URL) http.ResponseWriter {
    return &interceptor{w: wri, o: orig, t: targ}
}

func (i *interceptor) Header() http.Header { return i.w.Header() }

func (i *interceptor) WriteHeader(statusCode int) { i.w.WriteHeader(statusCode) }

func (i *interceptor) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    out := strings.ReplaceAll(string(b), i.o.Host, i.t.Host)
    fmt.Println(out)
    return i.w.Write(b)
}

func InterceptMiddleware(o url.URL, t url.URL) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            wrapped := NewResponseInterceptor(w, o, t)
            next.ServeHTTP(wrapped, r)
        }

        return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
    }
}
```

When I change the return of the `func (i *interceptor) Write(b []byte) (int,error)` to `return i.w.Write([]byte(out))` the application doesn't work as expected.  Depending on the size of the HTML page, it either doesn't show the HTML at all or shows a fragment of the HTML file that is 32768 bytes in length.

I would greatly appreciate any tips you have, if there are better approaches, or what I might be doing wrong with this implementation.

Comment: I found this github post where they discussed adding a modifyResponse to the Echo framework which is similar to what I want to achieve: [link](https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1580#issuecomment-634997259)

The point about anything written to res.Body seems similar to what I am experiencing.  By intercepting the write I am only able to modify what has or hasn't been flushed?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the response intercept middleware approach to work so I tried using an intermediate proxy as follows:

1. Start a proxy running on localhost:8080 based on this: https://gist.github.com/yowu/f7dc34bd4736a65ff28d
2. Start the file server running on localhost:10000
3. Configure my web browser to use the proxy running at localhost:8080
4. The response from line 74 of yowu's gist I do a replaceAll for the target URL

```
           network            proxy           fileserver
                              :8080            :10000
         .---------.       .---------.       .---------.
    <----|- - < - -|---<---|- - < - -|---<---|- < -|   |
you ---->|- - > - -|--->---|- -,- > -|--->---|- > -|   |
         |         |       |   |(*)  |       |         |
website<-|- - < - -|---<---|< -'     |       |         |
         |         |       |         |       |         |
         `---------´       `---------´       `---------´

(*) Modify the response from the fileserver to change the target URL
```

It does solve the problem but is more complex.  It would be great to know if there are any other approaches that are perhaps simpler.